# Removing brackets in my API request using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have an API script written in ruby that is returning data. The variable being used to return data is being passed includes brackets and quotes ["likeso"] resulting in no data being returned because it is expecting it to be only: likeso

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you parse the json string you will get only **likeso**

It's showing when you print the output.